# Angular#>= 1.0.8 resolved to angular#1.4.1 not 1.4.3

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I am using grunt and bower dependency management in my project. I wanted to add one external library:

https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64

The problem is that it depends on Angular#>= 1.0.8 and in my project I use 1.4.3. Maybe it is not a big deal, but I got an error

```
bower ECONFLICT     Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

I fixed it easily with

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.3"
}
```

But now i get the warning of

```
angular-base64#2.0.5 depends on angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to angular#1.4.1

angular-cookies#1.4.3, angular-resource#1.4.3, angular-route#1.4.3 depends on angular#1.4.3 which resolved to angular#1.4.3

Resort to using angular#1.4.3 which resolved to angular#1.4.3
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

I could of course change to 1.4.1 but I see not point in doing so. Why is this happening? Should I report it somewhere? Should I be worried about the incompatibilities? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
bower cache clean
```

There's nothing wrong with Angular `>= 1.0.8` dependency, it should resolve to the latest release, 1.4.3 ATM.